# Antiderivative of $\frac{1}{z}$ on $\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem 1:** Does $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ on $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ have an antiderivative?

**Solution:** We choose $\gamma(t)=e^{2\pi i t}, t\in[0,1], \quad \dot{\gamma}=2\pi i \gamma$

So: 
$$\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z}dz=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\gamma}2\pi i\gamma=2\pi i\neq 0$$

So using Cauchy's Integral Theorem, which states that any holomorphic function integrated over a closed path is zero and a antiderivative exists, there is no antiderivative.

**Problem 2:** Does $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ on $\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$  have an antiderivative?
**Solution:** Since $Log(z)$ (main branch) is continouse on $\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$ the antiderivative is $Log(z)$.

**Question:** Now, everything makes sense in the big picture. I do get that the main branch of the Logarithmus is continuous on that sliced plane. Also the first problem is clear. We took out the zero, making $\frac{1}{z}$ holomorphic.

But I still don't like my understanding here. The problem is: How would I derive the solution of Problem 2 properly? I want to see, in the math, the $\setminus (-\infty,0]$ part being somehow used. I wasn't able to, would be great is someone could show me. :)

Comment: The crucial difference is that the second domain is *simply connected.*

Comment: You can't apply Cauchy's integral theorem (maybe you meant the integral formula?) to $1/z$ as it's not analytic on an open simply connected domain containing your path.

Comment: The principal branch of the logarithm is continuous over $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$, as it is even differentiable there.

Comment: Your path $\gamma$ crosses into forbidden territory (namely when $t=\frac12$). So Cauchy does not apply.

Comment: Ok thanks guys, I think I should go back and look into Cauchy again :)